# Notepad++ - Searching for elevated lines that don't end with "\r

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am working in Notepad++ and I'm looking for a solution to an issue I'm having.
I have a few hundred thousand lines of code that I need to check with regex.

Basically, I need to check for any *elevated* lines (3-tabbed) that *don't* end with a parentheses and newline. ("\r)

Here's an example of the code:

```
    side
    {
        "id" "13"
        "plane" "(-1152 256 1) (-1152 256 -0) (2048 256 -0)"
        "material" "CONCRETE/CONCRETEFLOOR001A
        "uaxis" "[1 0 0 0] 0.25"
        "vaxis" "[0 0 -1 0] 0.25"
        "rotation" "0"
        "lightmapscale" "16"
        "smoothing_groups" "0"
    }
```

You can see that the Material line is missing a parentheses. I need a way to find these lines that are missing them.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\s+".*(?<!")$\r\n
```

This expression finds lines which:

- Starts with white spaces, following with a `"`
- Ends with `"` and new line character (`\r\n`)